# problem with putting objects created with constrsuctor into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple exercise with an object constructor. in this exercise, I create a form, and every time a user fills the form and clicks the show button, the data will send to an object constructor "Person" and every person's data will be put into the created object and then every object will be put into "myperson" array and print the array in the console.
but the problem is, the console only shows one index and the other indexes are empty.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click",get_data);
let i = 0;
function get_data() { 
    let myperson = [];
    let first_name = document.querySelector(".f_name").value;
    let last_name = document.querySelector(".l_name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector(".age").value;
     myperson[i++] = new Person(first_name, last_name, age);
    console.log(myperson);
    
}

function Person(f_name, l_name, age) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="" class="mt-5">
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> firstname </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control f_name" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> lastname  </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control l_name" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> age </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control age" value="">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"> show </button>
            
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

[image: console]

Comment: The reason you get `empty, Person` as an array is because you initialise the array, then increment your index of 0 by one _before_ using the index to assign a Person a position in your array. You could switch it by changing `i++` to `++i` (return value _before_ incrementing). It would actually be better to do `push` altogether so you don't have to worry about the index at all. (that and everybodys right: you need to turn this into a global variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myPerson should be a global variable, when put myPerson inside the method it will be initialized every time you call the method. Here's the modified code:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click",get_data);
const myperson = [];
function get_data() { 
    let first_name = document.querySelector(".f_name").value;
    let last_name = document.querySelector(".l_name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector(".age").value;
     myperson[myperson.length] = new Person(first_name, last_name, age);
    console.log(myperson);
    
}

function Person(f_name, l_name, age) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="" class="mt-5">
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> firstname </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control f_name" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> lastname  </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control l_name" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <label> age </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control age" value="">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"> show </button>
            
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: myPerson should be a global variable, when put myPerson inside the method it will be initialized every time you call the method

Comment: Hey Ayah, could you just add your comment to the answer? Now your answer is just random code with no guidance, and nobody is looking in the comments for clarification of the actual answer. Include it in the appropriate place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should declare you array outside the `get_data` function, in general it should be somewhere globally declared. Now it is created every time get_data is called, hence you always have a new array containing only the last person obj.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. you have set `let i = 0;` so every time when user will click on show button it will override the existing one.

instead of setting i=0 first get the count of array and then set i= count+1;

2. you are initializing array every time `let myperson = [];` due to which older is getting removed from existing array instead you and create a global variable.

Comment: Actually, if you are using the `count` (length), keep in mind that the `length` of the array is actual the last index + 1 (as 1 item in an array means the last index is `0`) so all you need is `array.length`. But still, `push` might have been a better thing to point towards.

Comment: @somethinghere yes true!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to declare the `myperson` array outside the `get_data` function so that it maintains the previously added person objects. Here's the modified code:

```js
    let myperson = [];

document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click",get_data);
let i = 0;
function get_data() { 
    let first_name = document.querySelector(".f_name").value;
    let last_name = document.querySelector(".l_name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector(".age").value;
     myperson[i++] = new Person(first_name, last_name, age);
    console.log(myperson);
    
}

function Person(f_name, l_name, age) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click",get_data);
let i = 0;
function get_data() { 
    let myperson = [];
    let first_name = document.querySelector(".f_name").value;
    let last_name = document.querySelector(".l_name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector(".age").value;
     myperson[i++] = new Person(first_name, last_name, age);
    console.log(myperson);
    
}

function Person(f_name, l_name, age) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the array each time you click the button.
moved the myperson outside the function to keep it.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-danger").addEventListener("click",get_data);

var myperson = [];
function get_data() { 
    let first_name = document.querySelector(".f_name").value;
    let last_name = document.querySelector(".l_name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector(".age").value;
    let person = new Person(first_name, last_name, age);
    myperson.push(person);
    console.log(myperson);
    
}

function Person(f_name, l_name, age) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    this.age = age;
}
```